# htaccess basic auth allow only one directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal-6, basic-authentication

I am using Drupal 6.

I am trying to use htaccess basic auth to block access to my development site. I have sucessfully added the auth so that only our developers can access it.

But now i want allow anyone to access one module (its links starts with anon/).

For ex: lets assume my site is `testsite.com`

i want to block all requests to all the pages expect `testsite.com/anon/*`

is it possible? if yes how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: first reply didn't work. Here's how to do it:

Check the documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#require, which says this:

```
<Directory /path/to/protected/>
  Require user david
</Directory>
<Directory /path/to/protected/unprotected>
  # All access controls and authentication are disabled
  # in this directory
  Satisfy Any
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is for Apache 2, btw.

Comment: You'd want to use `LocationMatch` instead, since you need to match based on requested URL.

Comment: Actually neither will work, since Require only works within Directory context, according to the docs.

Comment: Thilo, its not working. I am getting an 500 internal server error when i try this

Comment: Then check your error log file and see what caused the 500 error.

Comment: I've same case but still asking password,!!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/anon
RewriteRule ^(.*) error.html [L]
```

I can't be sure what I understand is the same as what you want to express.
I'm a Chinese and my English is not good~_~

Comment: That will deny ANYONE access to anything other than /anon/*, regardless of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Since I stumbled over this and it cost me some time:

The accepted answer is wrong, **it is not possible**.
(@Thilo, the answerer says so in the comments).

`<Directory>` directives don't work in `.htaccess` context, only in server config or virtual host context ([docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory)). @Thilo's config will work if you put it that context (i.e. `httpd.conf`, `vhosts.conf`, or wherever you distro has it) — in `.htaccess`, you'll get a 500 Internal Server Error, just like OP.